# Code for Qualtrics empty div box to prevent youtube video pause and replay

Tags: html, css, youtube, qualtrics

My video on a qualtrics survey autoplays but I am looking to prevent replay and pause (from users clicking and using spacebar).

I read up a little and found a suggestion to put an empty div box over the youtube video and to put the 'disablekb' parameter to 1. How do I do this/whats the code for it?

Sorry I'm really new to all this still learning, my basics are only rudimentary coding in R and SPSS.

This was the original answer I found/read from:

"You can try putting a div container over the video with nothing on it. In other words a blank container the same size as the video itself. What this should do is when someone tries to click on it, they will actually be clicking on the transparent container over it and won't be able to pause. This should work. You may also need to change the z-index to make sure the blank div container is truly over the video. (Test div container first with a background color and if the colored box covers the video then you can go back and remove the color and it will work the same.) Good luck.

Also, set the disablekb parameter to 1 so that user cannot pause even by space-bar."

This is under the html view of the survey question on qualtrics:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" height="375" src="youtube.com/embed/mU15c9aZ5E8"; width="500"></iframe>
```

This is under 'inspection' of the above html:

```
<textarea id="InlineEditorElement" class="inlineEditor html-editor" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="inlineEditor" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Courier, monospace; font-weight: normal; padding: 2px 3px; border-width: 2px; left: 93px; top: 6979px; width: 716px; height: 375px; overflow: auto;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you have worked on

Comment: <iframe allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" height="375" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mU15c9aZ5E8" width="500"></iframe>

This is under the html view of the survey question on qualtrics

Comment: <textarea id="InlineEditorElement" class="inlineEditor html-editor" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="inlineEditor" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Courier, monospace; font-weight: normal; padding: 2px 3px; border-width: 2px; left: 93px; top: 6979px; width: 716px; height: 375px; overflow: auto;"></textarea>                                                              This is under 'inspection' of the above html

Comment: Please add the code directly in the question.